# Why setting extended property to master will also set the same extended property to occurrences?

Tags: rest, office365, recurrence, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to link events from outlook to events in my app. So I'm setting an extended property for each event from outlook (the ID from my app). 
The problem is that if I set an extended property for a series master, all the occurrences will have the same extended property, but I want each event, of any type, to have an unique extended property (ID from my app).

This is my GET url :

`https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{user}/events('{event_id}')?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String {GUID} Name EntityId')`

This is how I PATCH the event to add the extended property :

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{user}/events('{event_id}')
```

and this is the content:

```
{"SingleValueExtendedProperties": [{"PropertyId":"String {GUID} Name EntityId","Value":"1234"}]}
```

Is it possible to do what I want? Each individual event/occurrence to have it's own extended property? I don't find this anywhere on Microsoft documentation or other resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep.  Under the covers a recurring meeting is a *single* item in the Exchange store.  One of the props on that item is something called the recurrence blob which contains all of the "exceptions" that differ from the master.  By default, there are no exceptions, so when expanding the series (the blob), all occurrences inherit the properties from the master.  When you set extended prop X on the master, those are implicitly passed to the occurrences because they are not explicitly overridden by any exceptions.

So, if you want to have a different value for each occurrence, set the property on the occurrences rather than the master.